# simulating randomness

Tags: random, operating-system

I'm just curious...

How do you simulate randomness? How is it done in modern OS (Windows, Linux, etc.)?

Edit:
Okay, NOT JUST GENERATING RANDOM NUMBER, which can be just done with calling `rand()` functions in most high level programming languages.

But, I'm more concerned with how it is actually done in modern operating systems.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see:

[Pseudo-random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584566/pseudo-random-number-generator)

[True random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702/true-random-number-generator)

[Fast pseudo random number generator for procedural content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167735/fast-pseudo-random-number-generator-for-procedural-content)

[Create Random Number Sequence with No Repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880)

[How do you generate a random number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408/how-do-you-generate-a-random-number-in-c)

[Seeding a random number generator in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369636/seeding-a-random-number-generator-in-net)

[How to get random double value out of random byte array values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403572/how-to-get-random-double-value-out-of-random-byte-array-values)

[Fast pseudo random number generator for procedural content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167735/fast-pseudo-random-number-generator-for-procedural-content)

etc...